# Need help editing a script

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I want to create a script that takes the directory name as input and then parses through all the sub-directories in that directory and displays the count of the files in each sub-directory that have the date entered (in YYYYMMDD format) in the filename.

Right now I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

echo "Please enter date in YYYYMMDD format ";
read date;
dirList=`ls -d *`
for d in $dirList ; do
  count=`find $d -name "*$date*" | wc -l`
  echo $d : $count
done
```

This just pareses through all the sub-directories in the current directory and displays the solution correctly. How should I edit it to take input of the directory path and do the same in that directory?

Comment: The original code is all kinds of buggy. Look at what happens with directory names with spaces, for instance.

Comment: ...as a habit, consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions about it here.

Comment: I didn't consider that because the directories I'm dealing with cannot have spaces. They are in the format File1_YYYMMDD @CharlesDuffy

Comment: One of my former employers once lost terabytes of billing data backups when a buffer overflow dumped random garbage into a filename that was supposed to be 24 digits of hex data (and a shell script maintaining that directory's contents failed to adequately quote). Writing code that can handle only the conditions you expect to occur is a good way to be unable to handle bugs that occur when a condition you don't expect is encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know how to (1) read a directory name (from stdin, presumably, as that's where you're getting your input from), and (2) use that directory for the duration of your script's execution?

Nothing simpler:

```
read -p "Please enter directory to start from: " dir
cd "$dir" || exit
```

---

That said, the rest of the script could stand some bugfixing as well:

```
for d in */; do
  count=$(find "$d" -name "*${date}*" -printf '\n' | wc -l)
  echo "$d: $count"
done
```

---

Using `ls -d *` was buggy in several respects:

- It didn't actually limit itself to directories
- It string-split the results of `ls`, considering a directory named `dir with four words` to be four separate directories, `dir`, `with`, `four` and `words`
- It wasn't guaranteed to work correctly with directories containing nonprintable characters in their names (for which `ls` implementations' behavior differs).

---

Similarly, `echo $d : $count` is buggy due the lack of quotes:

- A directory named `dir with * wildcard` would have the `*` expanded into a list of all files and directories in the current directory.
- A directory with a tab in its name, or a run of several spaces, would have that information lost.

---

Similarly, `find "$d" -name "*${date}*" | wc -l` isn't guaranteed to be an accurate count either: If a filename contains newlines in its name, some implementations of `find` will include those in its output as literals, causing `wc` to count that file multiple times (for each newline); hence the `-printf '\n'` to print only a single newline, and not a name at all, for each file identified.